# Is there any shorthand notation for linear interpolation?

Tags: notation

It is quite common for me to encounter or manipulate expressions of the form
$$
   x + \alpha(y-x)
$$
or equivalently
$$
   (1 - \alpha) x + \alpha y
$$
where any of the expressions ($\alpha, x, y$) may be rather complicated. I am not happy with either the repetition of expressions or the fact that so many symbols are required for the very simple ternary operation "$\alpha$ of the way from $x$ to $y$". In my own notes (not intended for reading by anyone but myself), I've taken to writing this as
$$
   x \overset\alpha\rightharpoondown y
$$
which I think is both clearer and more elegant. Has anyone proposed a similar notation for this concept? I assume that even if such a proposal has been made, it hasn't caught on, since my internet searching hasn't turned anything up, but if there is even a minimally standard notation, I'd be interested to learn it.

Comment: The `pic` diagram programming language uses the notation `a[p,q]` for the point $a$ of the way between $p$ and $q$. I think `metafont` has something similar.

Comment: @MJD Thanks. After a little searching, it looks like the `pic` notation is  `a<p,q>` and `metafont`'s is `a[p,q]`, so they do have the same general form.

Comment: `pic` also accepts `a of the way between p and q`, which I suppose demonstrates the lack of a common notation.